# Create automatically growing data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am new to R so please excuse my ignorance and code syntax.

I'd like to build a data frame to which data scraped from a website is automatically accumulated as new rows. I spent a few hours searching around the internet but the closest code I found to what I am trying to achieve was [this one](https://www.displayr.com/automatically-append-new-data-to-a-dataset-using-displayr/). [This](https://win-vector.com/2015/07/27/efficient-accumulation-in-r/) may also be helpful.

Here below you can find what I have written so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# Fetch stocks' quotes from website
web <- read_html("https://uk.investing.com/indices/spain-35-components")

# Transform into tables
tables <- web %>% html_table()

# Select desired table and make the adequate changes to simplify next steps
Investing_df <- tables[[2]] %>%
select(
  where(
    ~sum(!is.na(.x)) > 0
  )
) %>%
rename(Var_pct=`Chg. %`) %>%
select(-High, -Low, -Chg., -Vol., -Last, -Time) %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Var_pct)

# Create the empty df to accumulate the stocks' variations inside
columns <- as.character(colnames(Investing_df))

## Create a df with 0 rows and 35 columns (35 components of the index)
live_var <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(columns)))

## Assign column names
colnames(live_var)=columns
```

What I have done so far is:

1. A data frame from which I want to source the updated stock variations and
2. An empty data frame that needs to be fed with the live data in order to accumulate it

I want to create a script that automatically scrapes and inserts the new variations inside a data frame. I am aware that using a function is faster than for loop.

I hope I have explained myself clearly enough, if not please let me know so that I can edit this post.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you trying to append a row to the dataframe each n internal of time?

Comment: @Qharr Yes that is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to append a row of data at certain intervals. I will ignore the setting of intervals for now, and show how you could use user-defined functions to either generate a csv, on first call, or append with later calls. You could then run the calls from a cron schedule for example.

However, I will remark that I would want, if this were my program, to keep the depth of dataframe, rather than the widening, as I would want to pull in the time column; this would allow me to filter out potential duplicates later. It would also allow me to filter on certain stocks were the list to change (don't know if that could happen). Your current method is built on the assumption these 35 remain the same.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_row <- function(){
  
  web <- read_html("https://uk.investing.com/indices/spain-35-components")
  
  table <- web %>% html_node('#cr1') %>% html_table()
  
  investing_df <- table %>%
    select(
      where(
        ~sum(!is.na(.x)) > 0
      )
    ) %>%
    rename(var_pct=`Chg. %`) %>%
    select(Name, var_pct) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = var_pct)
    return(investing_df)
}

write_row <- function(file_name, df){
  flag <- file.exists(file_name)
  write.table(df, file = file_name, sep = ",",
              append = flag, 
              quote = F, col.names = !flag, 
              row.names = F)
}


file_name <- 'Investing.csv'
df <- get_row()
write_row(file_name, df)
```

Comment: #QHarr thank you very much. Tomorrow I will try it in my code and give you some feedback. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @QHarr, unfortunately the code you have written doesn't accumulate the stock variations because it creates a new df each time it is run. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes a new df for each run, that is by design. It appends to the csv. How did you implement it? I tested with multiple runs and it added rows.  The rows accumulate in the csv as your record over time.

Comment: yes I just understood your code. It now works perfectly. Thank you again.